# Why cannot a const struct field be used as an initializer in C?

Tags: c, struct, initialization, constants

Consider the following example:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

struct mystruct_s {
  uint16_t first;
};
typedef struct mystruct_s mystruct_t;

#define THEVALUE 5
const mystruct_t mytester = {
  .first = THEVALUE,
};

struct otherstruct_s {
  uint16_t initial;
};
typedef struct otherstruct_s otherstruct_t;

otherstruct_t othertester = {
  .initial = mytester.first,
};

int main() {
  printf("Hello, world %d!\n", othertester.initial);
  return 0;
}
```

When I build this in https://replit.com/languages/c I get:

```
> clang-7 -pthread -lm -o main main.c
main.c:20:23: error: initializer element is not a
      compile-time constant
  .initial = mytester.first,
             ~~~~~~~~~^~~~~
1 error generated.
exit status 1
```

I was kind of hoping, that since `mytester` is declared `const`, and its its `.first` field is initialized through a define, the compiler would have figured out that I want the same initialization applied to `othertester.initial`, but apparently not.

In my actual code, `gcc` was highlighting `mytester`, while here `clang` did in fact point to the field by highlighting, which indeed is not const - is this why I cannot initialize in this case?

Anyways, I have a similar (though much more convoluted) actual case; and while I'm aware that I can just use the define to initialize, I would really like to instead initialize via `mytester.first` for readability. Is there any workaround where I can use that, *without* having to define a copy of `mystruct_s` where the `.first` field is `const`?

Comment: I just compiled and ran your posted code without issue. gcc (Ubuntu 9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04) 9.3.0.

Comment: Fundamentally, the reason is that allowing objects to be initialized with other objects, even if they are `const`, would require the compiler to track what is stored in objects. Nothing in the C standard currently requires this—all the initializers a compiler is required to support are either values the compiler can compute directly from “compile-time constants” (essentially literals and expressions of them) or things the linker/loader can fill in (addresses).

Comment: @SimonGoater And...? gcc is notoriously a non-conforming non-C compiler unless you explicitly use `-std=c17 -pedantic-errors`.

Comment: Although soon to be standard C (C23): `otherstruct_t othertester = { .initial = (constexpr mystruct_t) { .first = THEVALUE }.first };` gcc (trunk) `-std=c2x` accepts it.

Comment: Thanks all, good to be aware there is more difference in compilers than I realized at first ...

Comment: Thanks @EricPostpischil - good explanation of why the OP approach did not work; could be an answer

Comment: Thanks @Lundin - that soon-to-be-standard would have been great; although if it is "soon-to-be", I guess there is no other current workaround, but to just use the define

Comment: @sdbbs You could download a _very_ recent gcc build (gotta be newer than 12.2) for your system and use `-std=c2x` until formal release. `constexpr` will be in it since it has been voted through by the committee. The standard just needs to be formalized and then every compiler vendor has to implement all the new features.

Comment: Or just use https://godbolt.org/ with "x86-64 gcc (trunk)", that's what I just did.